# ¿error para convertir un numero a string y concatenarlo?

Tags: c++, c

tengo una gran cantidad de errores en este codigo,ya busque algunas ayudas pero no se como solucionarlo,he corregido errores por comillas   y cree un arreglo to_string(n1[i]) en vez de to_string(i)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int ip; 
    cin>>ip;
    std::vector<int> n1(ip);
    std::vector<string> IPs(ip);

    for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i)
    {
        n1[i] = i;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){       
     
        IPs[i] = "user" + to_string(n1[i]) + "@gmail.com";

     }












    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Y puedes enumerar esos errores? Son errores de que tipo? De compilación? No obtienes el resultado esperado? A primera vista y [probando el código](https://tio.run/##jVDBasMwDD3XXyGyQxPCRtNj65ldd9t9GyO4bhAkcnCcXUq/PVMt0jAKpTrY8vPTew/Zvn@2bU3NND0h2XY8ONDohxhc3Rm1YL/ORh@MUkgRuhopL04KuNJxAbHfy2OIh93OIhnD0IKIgmaqAapy7Ivbz9SzOVJj4P1jEFaiHX2APPnAK2z2fOlkWZZYgES5FFWf@M0MFPHzkvGewGkev@qwuQhl4@BCBqXkjP5H4uXJqGA8e2t4H@2L9V02mz6SeCV78mMErWc/7tZftP6nE1wcA7GCgvM0Vds/) no hay errores aparentes.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no le veo ningun fallo, solo falta que solicites por pantalla la cantidad de elementos que tendran los dos vectores y por ultimo que muestres los resultados

```
int main() {
    int ip;

    cout<<"Indique cantidad de elementos a ingresar: ";
    cin>>ip;

    vector<int> n1(ip);
    vector<string> IPs(ip);

    for(int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){
        n1[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){
        IPs[i] = "user" + to_string(n1[i]) + "@gmail.com";
    }

    for(auto &e : IPs){
        cout<<e<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: lo volví a compilar y ya no me salta ningún error, se arreglo solo